# Bitcoin Core says it's synced but Blocks folder goes to only 985

Tags: mac, block

I just downloaded and synced bitcoin core v0.14.2 (64-bit).  After several days, it is now synced and (the check mark icon) says "up to date processed 483001 blocks of transaction history"  but when I view the blocks in my Bitcoin/blocks directory, it only goes up to block 00985 (rev00985.dat). Are the other blocks somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number 00985 is not the block number.

Bitcoin Core stores its blocks in 128 MiB block files (blk?????.dat), and corresponding undo data in rev?????.dat. Only when one block fills up, a new file is created.

Comment: I did find the bk???.dat files but again only to bk00985.bat. Where can I find the others?  Thanks.

Comment: There are no others. Read my answer.